# Install cryptography python module in Python notebook on Bluemix

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud, data-science-experience

As suggested [here](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-linux) I am trying

```
  !sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev
  !sudo yum install gcc libffi-devel python-devel openssl-devel
  !pip install cryptography
```

which does not work, because I am not allowed to run commands as `root`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `!pip install --user cryptography` from a Python notebook.

Explanation: It is correctly stated that one cannot become `root` on the system. Thus, you cannot run any of the first two commands at all. Also `pip install <package>` will require access on the system that you do not have. You can tell `pip` to install things in the user context by providing the `--user` option.
As for the first two commands, you don't need (one of) them, they are already satisfied; the libs are already installed system-wide.